# Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 install repeatedly crashes with ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: server, 22.04

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 from a bootable USB created with the file `ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso`. The computer is a fitlet2 with 16 gigs of RAM and a 500GB SSD. The installation starts as expected and then crashes at various points in the install process. Sometimes this is immediately after choosing my language, sometimes it's further along. The error however is always the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/snap/subiquity/3698/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1144, in _create_connection
      _, proto = await self._loop.create_unix_connection(
    File "/snap/subiquity/3698/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 244, in create_unix_connection
      await self.sock_connect(sock, path)
    File "/snap/subiquity/3698/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 496, in sock_connect
    File "/snap/subiquity/3698/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 501, in _sock_connect
      sock.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection Refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

...
<output truncated>
...

aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectionError: Cannot connect to host a:80 ssl:default [Connection refused]
```

I've tried the install both with and without networking configured (when I'm able to get that far into the install process). I've also searched and haven't found anyone having a similar problem. Also, when I configure networking to be enabled I can see DNS requests from the computer passing through my router so I know it has a good network connection. What is the underlying issue causing this `ClientConnectionError`? And what is the host `a:80` that it's attempting to connect to?

Thanks!

Comment: This sort of issue usually points to a corrupted `.iso` download or incomplete write to the USB. Have you [verified the download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview)? 

Comment: I did, yeah. I also just now swapped out the thumb drive to see if that was the issue and got the same result.

Comment: The installer (_subiquity_) has a client process and a server process.  They communicate over a unix socket using the `a` hostname.  This failure is the client unable to connect to the server.  I would suspect not enough RAM, but 16GB is plenty.  My next guess is also a corrupted iso.